# BigQuery: fill null for missing column in table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query to show daily aggregation based on some metrics. something like

```
select date(timestamp), metric, count(*) from aggs GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Problem is sometime certain metric is missing for certain day like:

```
date  | metric | count
03/01 |   B    |    50
03/02 |   A    |    60
03/02 |   B    |    10
03/02 |   C    |    70
03/03 |   C    |    10
```

I want to fill in 0 or null for missing date/metric pair - ie how can we do something like:

```
date  | metric | count
03/01 |   A    |     0
03/01 |   B    |    50
03/01 |   C    |     0
03/02 |   A    |    60
03/02 |   B    |    10
03/02 |   C    |    70
03/03 |   A    |     0
03/03 |   B    |     0
03/03 |   C    |    10
```

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct so it doesn't particularly help the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the query, mind taking a look now?

Comment: @Kauki . . . That doesn't change my answer.  You can just use your query as a CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join` and then fill in the values using a `left join`:

```
select date, metric, coalesce(t.count, 0)
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct metric from t) m left join
     t
     using (date, metric);
```

If you don't have all dates that you want, you can use:

```
unnest(generate_date_array(<date1>, <date2>, interval 1 day)) u(dte)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do time-series null-exposure in BigQuery. If the query performance is not an issue, then the easier way to do it is

```
WITH original_result AS (
  SELECT date(timestamp) as date, metric, count(*) 
  FROM aggs 
  GROUP BY 1,2
)

SELECT
  *
FROM 
  UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(<start_date>, <end_date>, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS date
LEFT JOIN original_result USING (date)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```